# Safecracker prefixing directory name to uploaded file

Tags: matrix, safecracker, file-uploads, filename

Has anyone had an instance like this?

I have a Matrix field which contains a Safecracker File upload field.

When I upload a file via this (in the regular control panel) the file uploads but the name has the directory prepended to it.

Say the file was called "my_document.pdf" and was uploaded to a directory named "documents" would be called "documentsmy_document.pdf".

EDIT: I have actually "fixed" this now but I don't know if my fix will cause problems further down the line.

Looking at ft.safecracker_file.php I figured that save method was to blame. Towards the end there is a ternary conditional that prefixes the upload directory name to the file. I've changed that line so it doesn't.

Changing:
    $output = ($data && isset($this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir']) && $data !== 'NULL') ? '{filedir_'.$this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir'].'}'.$data : '';

To:
    $output = ($data && isset($this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir']) && $data !== 'NULL') ? $data : '';

Has 'solved' the issue for me but I'm unsure as to whether this was an intentional thing to avoid clashes of filenames that are in different directories - I can't really see how that could happen though. It all seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually "fixed" this now but I don't yet know if my fix will cause any problems further down the line.

Looking at ft.safecracker_file.php I figured that save method was to blame. Towards the end there is a ternary conditional that prefixes the upload directory name to the file. I've changed that line so it doesn't.

Changing:

```
$output = ($data && isset($this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir']) && $data !== 'NULL') ? '{filedir_'.$this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir'].'}'.$data : '';
```

To:

```
$output = ($data && isset($this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir']) && $data !== 'NULL') ? $data : '';
```

This has 'solved' the issue for me but I'm unsure as to whether this was an intentional thing to avoid clashes of filenames that are in different directories - I can't really see how that could happen though. It all seems a bit odd.

UPDATE:
I've seen some weirdness with some Safecracker fields not returning any data (although passing a conditional check to see if they're populated). This could well be related to my hack - although again I am not sure why. The data in these fields was existing prior to my hack and they were working afterwards but suddenly stopped working.

Changing the fieldtype to a regular file field and back to a Safecracker file field *seems* to have sorted it so I am not sure what happened.